# Onclick event for image tag inside PHP echo, is not working

Tags: php, javascript

In my image.php file i have code

```
$id=abs($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM table1 WHERE id=$id");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $data['image'];
```

And while retrieving i am using query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1");
  while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo '<'.'img src="image.php?id='.$data['id'].'">';
```

It is perfectly displaying images from my data base...
But i want to detect which image user clicked for that i tried

```
echo '<'.'img src="image.php?id='.$data['id'].'" onclick="doSomething()">';
```

this onclick java script function doesn't getting call..(i am using mozilla fire fox)
I am new to PHP.

Finally I need to detect the clicked image among the images which are displayed using PHP echo from Mysql.Is there any other way that i can follow for this?

Comment: What is rendered html? Did you check rendered page source (view source), maybe has syntax error?

Comment: Why are you concatenating '<' and the rest of the string? '<img..' would work the same

Comment: Check your error console in Firefox. Check that `doSomething()` is actually defined, keep in mind the function name is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<'.'img src="image.php?id='.$data['id'].'" onclick="doSomething(this.id)" 
id="img_'.$data['id'].'">';
```

try this and in dosomething use ajax andpass id to PHP and process it

Comment: For first Onclick is not getting call on this for me.Is it correct syntax that i wrote?

Comment: This code has a syntax error. You can't use variables inside a single quoted string, the PHP interpreter does not parse them. Concatenate the `$data['id']` part in the `id` attribute. I would also suggest a prefix on the `id` like `id="img_x"`.

Comment: yup..it will be echo '<'.'img src="image.php?id='.$data['id'].'" onclick="doSomething(this.id)" 
id="'.$data['id'].'">'

Comment: IIRC IDs cannot be just numeric

Comment: I am displaying images from my database.using code as i shown above.now i need to detect which image is clicked when i click some image on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in escaping quotes

```
echo" < img src='image.php?id=". $data['id']. "' onclick='doSomething()' >";
```

Comment: echo '<img src= "1.jpeg" onclick="alert("alert")>';   it displaying image but onclick is not working for this too..

Comment: echo '<img src= "1.jpeg" onclick="alert(\"alert\")>';  try this

Comment: Then check if your javascript tag `<script type='text/javascript'> function doSomething() {} </script>`

Answer (score 0):

put the image inside a link tag.

`echo '<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()"><img src="image.php?id='.$data['id'].'"></a>';`

Comment: echo '<a onclick="alert(\'alert\');"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>'; this should work fine!

Comment: Put a `href` attribute in the link

Comment: Yeah, it should have, thanks, I just forgot, but it's not that what is causing  the problem once I got it working as it is in my comment...

Comment: even i have tried like using                                      echo'<a href = "#" onclick="alert("alert");"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>' it displaying image for me but onclick is not getting called if i put it in either anchor tag or image tag.

Comment: Did you notice that I changed the quotes? copy and paste my code and have a look...

Comment: Thank you Tadeu Zagallo its working now. I am struggling from 3 hrs thank you very much.

Comment: but if i put                                                       echo'<a onclick="do();"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>';                   and alert("alert"); inside do() it is not working again.

Comment: This should have `image.php?id='.$data['id']` not `image.php?'.$data['id']`

Comment: So the problem should be with your function definition... is it above of the image? edit and post your output html if it's possible. I really don't like to use that... why not use eventListener?
and thanks @MrCode I'm just fast looking because I'm at the work.

Comment: the `do()` refers to the function , therefore it doesn't matter if there are quotes in the function itself.

Comment: Your function name is really `do`? because `do` is a reserved word... try `function Do() { alert('test'); }`

Comment: @tadeuzagallo can you please tell me how to show my php variable value in alert. Thanks in advance