# onclick event is not working inside echo

Tags: php, javascript

```
echo '<a onclick="alert(\'alert\');"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>';
```

It is working fine, But

```
echo '<a onclick="do();"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>';
```

Its not working if i put that alert inside do() like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function do()
{
    alert("alert");
}
</script>
```

Can any body help on this.

Comment: So why you marked as accepted [your previous analogue answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601583/onclick-event-for-image-tag-inside-php-echo-is-not-working)? :o

Comment: its working on first condition when i marked.but when i check with second it is not working.

Comment: I am new to this site..Just i just confused with this comment styles and options.And i just missed the link after i gave the mark.

Answer (score 1):

`do` is a reserved word in javascript. Try naming the method something else.

Comment: Even not working, I tried wit the name                             echo '<a onclick="doin();"><img src= "1.jpeg"></a>';

Comment: @AshokiPhone You can use [Chrome web inspector](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html#access) or Firefox [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to read what errors javascript parser gives to you. It should be a great help for you

Comment: Then it sounds like the javascript isn't loaded as it should be. Could you update your original question with some detail on the context in which you use the code? How do you load the javascript etc.

Comment: @AshokiPhone: With the code in your original post, it does not work for me. If the only thing that I change in your code is to change the function name to `doin` and update the call to match, it does work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a function named do(). Change the name to something else. Also, it would be a good idea to use something like:

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="your_function();return false;">
        <img src="img.jpg">
      </a>';
```

Comment: Please `return false` onclick instead of `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: @mplungjan: I hope the edit is what you suggested that should have been done ?

Comment: Yes, but retain the href - I like href="#" but others at SO do not since it does reload the page but ONLY if javascript is turned off because of the return false